# After 6 days my app is still not visible in Google Play Search

Tags: android, search, google-play

My App was approved in Google Play Market 6 days ago, but it still cannot be found in search.

How long does it take until my app and developer name can be found in search ?

I have installs only from direct links and from my website

Answer (score 0):

Usually doesn't take any longer than six hours. Are you sure that you published the app rather than simply saving the draft? If you open the Google Play Developer console just check your app. If you open the app in the console check up on the top right.

Comment: sorry I had to remove the link, but the app is visible in google play only from direct link.

Comment: Only from direct link rather than by search in Google Play? Off memory first publishing of an apk will still take a day or two. If it is available from the direct link just give it an another day or so and check. Google may only update Play stores search system once a week or something. But that's just speculation.

Comment: It was published and available on direct link since 1 july.

Comment: What is the app called and I'll see if I can find it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try scrolling down the results list? From my experience google tends to display bunch of other apps that have different name then axact search phrase but are more popular or sth

Comment: if i put my app name in quotes "my app" then it finds it, otherwise not, and even my developer name cannot be found without quotes

Comment: It's nowhere down in the list.